# How to express an is/too-much gap?

Tags: aristotle, virtue-ethics, deontic-logic

Phrases like "too much" and "not enough" can be morally charged fairly easily, so how would we express the fact/value distinction in these terms? I was thinking of using special quantifiers:

- ∀*na*, ∃<sub>*n*</sub>*aFa* ⊬ ∃<sub>too many/few</sub>*aFa*

Is that sufficient? I had in mind modeling Aristotle's doctrine of the mean, where degenerate and excessive solutions to first-order aretaic problems are the very meaning of "not enough" and "too much," here.

Comment: This is good but too restricted, I think Hume's guillotine is intended more globally. *Any* collection of sentences with only ordinary quantifiers (and no deontic operators) does not entail a sentence with "too much" or "not enough". This would require second order quantification to express.